# grouped Violin plot with two chosen colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to built a grouped violin plot with a box plot. I have two datasets for which I would like to fill the violin with two colors of my choice. Here it is gold3 and green4.

I can built a violin plot without choosing the colors (script1) or using the viridis color package (script2). However I am unable to write a script allowing me to choice the colors (ex: script3). I did several attempts, the script 3 is one example. Is somebody could save my day?

```
# Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(viridis)
library(readxl)

# script 1 : without selecting a color  
  IP %>%
    left_join(sample_size) %>%
    mutate(class = paste0(class, "\n", "n=", num)) %>%
    ggplot( aes(x=class, y=FC, fill = class)) +
    geom_violin(trim = FALSE, width=0.5, color="black") +
    geom_boxplot(width=0.1, fill="white", alpha=1) +
    theme_ipsum() +
    theme(legend.position="none",  plot.title = element_text(size=11)) +
    ggtitle("dark / light") +
    xlab("")
                      

  #script 2: using the viridis color package ; scale_fill_viridis ()
  IP %>%
    left_join(sample_size) %>%
    mutate(class = paste0(class, "\n", "n=", num)) %>%
    ggplot( aes(x=class, y=FC, fill = class)) +
    geom_violin(trim = FALSE, width=0.5, color="black") +
    geom_boxplot(width=0.1, fill="white", alpha=1) +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
    theme_ipsum() +
    theme(legend.position="none", plot.title = element_text(size=11)) +
    ggtitle("dark / light") +
    xlab("")
  
  #script 3 : with the colors of my choice ; using scale_fill_manual()
  IP %>%
    left_join(sample_size) %>%
    mutate(class = paste0(class, "\n", "n=", num)) %>%
    ggplot( aes(x=class, y=FC, fill = class)) +
    geom_violin(trim = FALSE, width=0.5, color="black") +
    geom_boxplot(width=0.1, fill="white", alpha=1) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("gold3","green4") +
    theme_ipsum() +
    theme(legend.position="none",  plot.title = element_text(size=11)) +
    ggtitle("dark / light") +
    xlab("")
```

```
> dput(IP[1:10,  ])
structure(list(accession = c("AT1G02780", "AT1G04410", "AT1G06220", 
"AT1G09570", "AT1G09590", "AT1G12310", "AT1G13440", "AT1G14320", 
"AT1G18080", "AT1G18450"), class = c("dark", "dark", "dark", 
"dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark"), FC = c(4.59119684525637, 
1.93792296315229, 4.89823218971082, 3.11452479089177, 4.64624642749372, 
4.40162610414297, 2.40498023702838, 5.93428160589643, 4.58614792693447, 
2.26967533882607), iBAQ = c(0.0043428541569438, 0.000856437090950815, 
0.000215800833628843, 0.0001869458465772, 0.00133274539235563, 
0.000700545801420077, 0.0384210662362482, 0.00368689662888386, 
0.000594557208423326, 0.000117271126660639), label = c("AT1G02780.1|RPL19A (60S / eL19)|Ribosomal protein L19e family proteinmRNA binding|translation|RP - cytosolic|", 
"AT1G04410.1|MDH1|Lactate/malate dehydrogenase family proteinmRNA binding|", 
"AT1G06220.1|CLO|110 kDa U5 small nuclear ribonucleoprotein component CLO [Source:UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot|", 
"AT1G09570.1|PHYA|phytochrome AmRNA bindingtranscription, DNA-templated|regulation of transcription, DNA-templatedtranslation|regulation translation|", 
"AT1G09590.1|RPL21A|Translation protein SH3-like family protein|", 
"AT1G12310.1|CML13|Calcium-binding EF-hand family protein|", 
"AT1G13440.1|GAPC2|glyceraldehyde-3-phosphate dehydrogenase C2|", 
"AT1G14320.1|RPL10A (60S / uL16)|Ribosomal protein L16p/L10e family proteinmRNA binding|translation|RP - cytosolic|ribosome biogenesis", 
"AT1G18080.1|RACK1A (40S / RACK1)|Transducin/WD40 repeat-like superfamily proteinmRNA binding|translation|RP - cytosolic|ribosome associated_GOribosome biogenesistranslation elongation|regulation translation|", 
"AT1G18450.1|ARP4|actin-related protein 4transcription, DNA-templated|regulation of transcription, DNA-templated"
), name = c("RPL19A (60S / eL19)", "MDH1", "CLO", "PHYA", "RPL21A", 
"CML13", "GAPC2", "RPL10A (60S / uL16)", "RACK1A (40S / RACK1)", 
"ARP4")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

In the script 3, the plot is not produced and the following message  appears :

```
Error in auto_copy(x, y, copy = copy) : 
  argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible by either demonstrating using a built-in data set or sharing enough of your data for us to use it to construct a solution. `dput()` is an easy way to share a sample of your data, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:10,  ])` for the first 10 rows. Please use `dput` on the data **after** you join and mutate it, as those steps are presumably not part of the problem.

Comment: It would also help if you were more specific about the issues with your `script 3` code. What doesn't work about it? Is there an error or warning? Do the colors not show up? Do they show up differently than you expected?

Comment: Thank you Gregor for your feedback. I edited my answer to include your recommandations.

Comment: Your script 3 code is missing a `)` at the end of the `scale_fill_manual` line. Addin that, it seems to run fine on the sample data you shared.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added a parenthesis. I will double check the next time. It didn't worked at first. However, I rebooted my computer and it worked finally.